# Piecewise Equation Formatting Issue in MathJax Preview

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, formatting, markdown-preview

I am composing a question involving piecewise polynomial equations, but the preview formatting isn't coming out how I expect. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

The notation I'm using:

```
j(t) = s_{max}\,×\,\begin{cases}
0 & : -∞ < t < 0 \\
f_{01}(0) × (t - T_{01}) + f_{01}(1) & : 0 ≤ t < T_{01} \\
f_{02}(0) × (t - T_{02}) + f_{02}(1) & : T_{01} ≤ t < T_{02} \\
f_{03}(0) × (t - T_{03}) + f_{03}(1) & : T_{02} ≤ t < T_{03} \\
f_{04}(0) × (t - T_{04}) + f_{04}(1) & : T_{03} ≤ t < T_{04} \\
f_{05}(0) × (t - T_{05}) + f_{05}(1) & : T_{04} ≤ t < T_{05} \\
f_{06}(0) × (t - T_{06}) + f_{06}(1) & : T_{05} ≤ t < T_{06} \\
f_{07}(0) × (t - T_{07}) + f_{07}(1) & : T_{06} ≤ t < T_{07} \\
f_{08}(0) × (t - T_{08}) + f_{08}(1) & : T_{07} ≤ t < T_{08} \\
f_{09}(0) × (t - T_{09}) + f_{09}(1) & : T_{08} ≤ t < T_{09} \\
f_{10}(0) × (t - T_{10}) + f_{10}(1) & : T_{09} ≤ t < T_{10} \\
f_{11}(0) × (t - T_{11}) + f_{11}(1) & : T_{10} ≤ t < T_{11} \\
f_{12}(0) × (t - T_{12}) + f_{12}(1) & : T_{11} ≤ t < T_{12} \\
f_{13}(0) × (t - T_{13}) + f_{13}(1) & : T_{12} ≤ t < T_{13} \\
f_{14}(0) × (t - T_{14}) + f_{14}(1) & : T_{13} ≤ t < T_{14} \\
f_{15}(0) × (t - T_{end}) + f_{15}(1) & : T_{14} ≤ t < T_{end} \\
0 & : T_{end} ≤ t < ∞ \\
\end{cases}
```

What I want it to look like (composed in LaTeX in an external program):

[image: Piecewise equation displaying properly]

What I'm getting in the Mathematics Stack Exchange question-editor preview:

[image: Piecewise equation displaying incorrectly]

And finally, the MathJax directly in this question:

$$
j(t) = s_{max}\,×\,\begin{cases}
0 & : -∞ < t < 0 \\
f_{01}(0) × (t - T_{01}) + f_{01}(1) & : 0 ≤ t < T_{01} \\
f_{02}(0) × (t - T_{02}) + f_{02}(1) & : T_{01} ≤ t < T_{02} \\
f_{03}(0) × (t - T_{03}) + f_{03}(1) & : T_{02} ≤ t < T_{03} \\
f_{04}(0) × (t - T_{04}) + f_{04}(1) & : T_{03} ≤ t < T_{04} \\
f_{05}(0) × (t - T_{05}) + f_{05}(1) & : T_{04} ≤ t < T_{05} \\
f_{06}(0) × (t - T_{06}) + f_{06}(1) & : T_{05} ≤ t < T_{06} \\
f_{07}(0) × (t - T_{07}) + f_{07}(1) & : T_{06} ≤ t < T_{07} \\
f_{08}(0) × (t - T_{08}) + f_{08}(1) & : T_{07} ≤ t < T_{08} \\
f_{09}(0) × (t - T_{09}) + f_{09}(1) & : T_{08} ≤ t < T_{09} \\
f_{10}(0) × (t - T_{10}) + f_{10}(1) & : T_{09} ≤ t < T_{10} \\
f_{11}(0) × (t - T_{11}) + f_{11}(1) & : T_{10} ≤ t < T_{11} \\
f_{12}(0) × (t - T_{12}) + f_{12}(1) & : T_{11} ≤ t < T_{12} \\
f_{13}(0) × (t - T_{13}) + f_{13}(1) & : T_{12} ≤ t < T_{13} \\
f_{14}(0) × (t - T_{14}) + f_{14}(1) & : T_{13} ≤ t < T_{14} \\
f_{15}(0) × (t - T_{end}) + f_{15}(1) & : T_{14} ≤ t < T_{end} \\
0 & : T_{end} ≤ t < ∞
\end{cases}
$$

There are no line breaks between the individual condition statements, and the notation `\,` isn't being converted into a space character.

I know that piecewise notation works on the Mathematics Stack Exchange in at least some situations, as I've used it before successfully. Here's an example from [one of my previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169332/is-there-a-pattern-to-the-coefficients-in-the-piecewise-equations-of-the-irwin-h):

```
f_X(x; 3) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x²}{2} & : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\
\frac{−2 x² + 6x − 3}{2} & : 1 < x ≤ 2 \\
\frac{(−x + 3)²}{2} & :  2 < x ≤ 3 \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
```

[image: Piecewise equation displaying properly in a previous question]

Weirdly, when I copy the MathJax directly from that question and paste it in here with no changes, which I did to get an example of MathJax working correctly, it ALSO doesn't display properly in the preview here, despite displaying correctly in the edit preview on that earlier question:

$$f_X(x; 3) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x²}{2} & : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\
\frac{−2 x² + 6x − 3}{2} & : 1 < x ≤ 2 \\
\frac{(−x + 3)²}{2} & :  2 < x ≤ 3 \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

EDIT: After posting this question, I saw that the MathJax is actually displaying correctly in the posted version despite not displaying correctly in the new-question-composing preview. In writing this edit, the MathJax is also displaying correctly in the existing-question-editing preview. So it seems like the problem is a bug in the new-question-composing preview, not a problem with my notation.

EDIT 2: I am on Windows 10 Pro 21H2, Firefox 111.0.1 (64-bit), MathJax Math Renderer HTML-CSS with nothing changed from default values.

Comment: You gotta tell us more about your environment - OS, browser, MathJax rendering options. Check previous MathJax/LaTeX questions for details on how to find the latter.

Comment: `\,` is never a "non-breaking-space". That codes for a "thin space", and it is not non-breaking in regular LaTeX either.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76132/how-to-typeset-a-small-non-breaking-space states that `\,` is non-breaking, and my experience using it is that it is *indeed* non-breaking.

Comment: @Lawton: In text mode, `\,` is a kern, so it is unbreakable, as described there. However, in math mode, `\,` is defined to be `\def\,{\mskip\thinmuskip}` (page 357 of the $\TeX$-book); `\thinmuskip` is a unit defined in terms of the mu (mathematical unit of space), and `\mskip` is a mathematical horizontal skip, which introduces glue; glue is stretchable/breakable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In that case there may be a bug in MathJax, or in Stack Exchange's implementation of it. When I use a regular space character a line break gets inserted there because the expression is so wide, but when I use `\,` no line break is inserted.

Comment: MathJax is does not (nor is it required to) faithfully reproduce $\TeX$s behaviour.